# Change current working directory in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm developing a CI for Python package in Azure Pipelines (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/azure-pipelines/azure-pipelines.yml). At some point, I need to step out of the source code directory to allow `pytest` to discover an installation of this package, and run the corresponding tests.

The issue I'm facing is related to the fact that `cd`, `cd C:`, etc commands do not seem to cause any effect, so that the current working directory remains unchanged (in this specific case, `D:\a\1\s`).

Is there a way to overcome the described limitation?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

It took many hours to find the solution, but, apparently, there **is** a way to specify working directory for specific script -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=vsts&tabs=yaml :

```
- script: # script path or inline
  workingDirectory: #
  displayName: #
  failOnStderr: #
  env:  # mapping of environment variables to add
```

Comment: Do you also know how to put it to the folder of the pipeline (which seems a common use case)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can just use `workingDirectory: subfolder/` at each step inside your YAML where subfolder is relative to repository root. You need this even if your pipeline is located at `subfolder/azure-pipeline.yml`

Comment: The answer just highlights that there is a `workingDirectory:` modifier. At the time of posting this info was really hard to find.

Answer (score 19):

Simple Solution to know the directory location in Azure devops :-

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      dir
      dir subfoldername
```

where you need to invoke the command line and get the current path by using System.DefaultWorkingDirectory and dir will list you all the folders and files
and using dir subfoldername we can traverse into subfolders