# Handling multiple azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have several azure devops pipeline files in one project. The files are all in a subdirectory and called `azure-pipelines.yml`.

**Renaming**: I can rename the pipelines in the UI to distinguish them... but I would like to skip that manual step and perform that in the yml. Is there a parameter for that - I cannot find it in the docs.

**Workdirs**: the pipelines start in the main directory. I can adjust the working directory of the script steps with `workingDirectory` thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857085/change-current-working-directory-in-azure-pipelines). But can we also adjust that for the entire pipeline?

Comment: Hi @Roelant. Did you check out below answer? Feel free to let me know if there is any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a parameter for renaming the pipelines. There are two ways to rename the pipelines. One is to manually rename them from the UI. Another way is through [build definition update rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Below is an example in powershell scripts to rename the pipeline through rest api. 
the scripts first get the build definition by [build definition get api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Then assign a new name for the build definition, and update the definition with the new name.

```
$create = "https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJ}/_apis/build/definitions/{DefinitionId}?api-version=5.1"

$PAT="{Person access token}"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $create -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method get 

$result.name = "YamlPipeline-newName"

$updateBody= $result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

$result7 =  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $create -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method put -ContentType application/json -Body $updateBody
```

You cannot change the workingdirectory for the entire pipeline. You can change the workingdirectory inside the tasks.

And there are [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables) you can use to refer to the places in the agents. 
For below example:

[image]

`$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` is mapped to  `c:\agent_work\1`

`%(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is mapped to `c:\agent_work\1\a`

`$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` is mapped to `c:\agent_work\1\b`

`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` is mapped to `c:\agent_work\1\s`

You can also [submit a feature request for above renaming pipeline and adjust workingdirectory for the entire pipeline](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click Suggest a feature and choose Azure Devops) to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider supporting these feature in the future.