# How to version control PowerApps project in DevOps repo

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps

Does anyone have any input or idea on how to add PowerApps projects into a DevOps repo.
I understand that PowerApps has it's own version control, but I was just wondering if there is a way to version control PowerApps codes into DevOps.

Comment: Hi Did you check out below steps, how did it go? Please let me if you have any question.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Thanks for the touch base, I have not been able to explore this option yet. I will update this at the soonest. Thanks

Comment: Hi @the.herbert. Hope below answer works out for you. Look forward to your update.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SolutionPackager tool to extract solution components.

**Step 1:** 
Export your solution using the Export-CrmSolution cmdlet

Export-CrmSolution -SolutionName "SolutionName" -Managed -SolutionZipFileName "SolutionName.zip"

**Step 2:**
Extract the solution

SolutionPackager.exe /action:extract /folder:.\package /zipfile:"SolutionName.zip" /packagetype:Both /allowDelete:Yes /c

You can add these steps in a powershell script that execute from a Post-Build event in Visual Studio, similar to this:

if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\SolutionExport.ps1)

Once this is done you can commit to your repo.

For more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/compress-extract-solution-file-solutionpackager

Answer (score 0):

I built a Power Automate Flow which will move your PowerApps Canvas apps to Github for version control. Its not perfect because the PowerApps "source code" has some strange features (such as a .jpg file with a dynamic name for every save!).

- [Flow](https://github.com/SeaDude/seattlePowerAppers/raw/master/flows/knownGood_20200422050652.zip)
- [Instructions](https://github.com/SeaDude/seattlePowerAppers/blob/master/outlines/powerappsVersionControl.md)

Comment: Your repo is not online anymore 

Answer (score -3):

If you have the Powerapps codes, it is very easy to push it into a azure devops repo. You can follow below steps.

However, it would be hard for you to version control the PowerApp project, for its source code is complicated and not nice to read. Please check [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-do-we-source-control-PowerApps-code/m-p/1454) for more information on Power Apps Community site.

1, create an empty repo from azure devops UI. Click **Repos** -> click the "+" beside the project name -> choose **New repository**. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps.

[image]

Then **uncheck** Add a README

[image]

After you create your repo. You will get a guide to add the repo url to your local git repo

[image]

2, Then In the local directory for the PowerApps codes. Run below git commad to create a local repo for PowerApps codes. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334570/how-to-import-project-code-from-local-machine-to-azure-repos) for more information

```
#Then In the local directory for the PowerApps codes

git init
git remote add origin <URL for Azure Git repo>
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push -u origin master
```

Then the powerapp codes will be pushed to azure git repo.