# Multiple CI pipelines in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are starting a brand new project using .Net Core Web Api and React to build a marketing tool.

In the past in different projects I was assigned to and the repo was already set up, we had one git repo for the back-end and another git repo for the front-end and each one of them having its own CI pipeline.

Now, for the new one, the requirement is to have both back-end and front-end in the same repo but different folder. So, just wondering if we can still have two CI pipelines with this structure. If so, could you share any documentation/ link how to achieve that?

Comment: Did you start by reading the documentation and experimenting?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, yes I did. I already marked the given response as done. However, I am facing a different problem now only for the Front-end pipeline. More details in the response section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to limit trigger access to specific folders. You need to have two build definitions and define there proper for your project `include` and `exclude` paths.

An example from [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

```
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs/*
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

Comment: @Krzystof, thanks for sharing it. I followed it up as well as the documentation. I created two separated pipelines and are working properly. The only thing is that the Front-end one is failing because at the moment to execute the npm install and build steps, it cannot find the project where the package.json file is located. I guess because the new folder structure. I will troubleshooting it.

Comment: You need probably set working directory for this step. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857085/change-current-working-directory-in-azure-pipelines

Comment: Thanks for the link. I figured it out following some steps on the documentation. Now both front-end and back-end CI pipelines are working properly.