# Set working directory in azure devops with Visual Studio build task

Tags: visual-studio, build, azure-devops, msbuild

I'm trying to build a project which requires to set the **working directory** to a path.

On my local machine I could go with Visual Studio 2019 and go to *Project* - *Properties* - *Debugging* - *Command Arguments* and set it to whatever I want. The problem is that I don't know how to do with ***Visual Studio build task***.

If I do not set this settings, it produces an executable that doesn't launch.

here is my build pipeline: https://dev.azure.com/nathanvalletmarseille/armorpaint/_build?definitionId=5&_a=summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not able to directly set this with build-in visual studio build task.

However, you could do this through a [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) before you run the build task:

```
- script: # script path or inline
  workingDirectory: #
  displayName: #
  failOnStderr: #
  env:  # mapping of environment variables to add
```

More details take a look at this similar question: [Change current working directory in Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857085/change-current-working-directory-in-azure-pipelines)

Comment: hello, do you mean doing cd mydirectory or set it in the working directory parameter?

Comment: And do i would need to run Visual studio trough command line?

Comment: @Xephobia  You can just use `workingDirectory: subfolder/` at each step inside your YAML where subfolder is relative to repository root. Actually the sample is using YAML pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema Yes, you need to call MSBuild command line to run the build.